# Валидация input по минимальной сумме

Tags: javascript

В поле `input` необходимо определить минимальную сумму 100, в случае ввода меньшего числа валидатор выдает ошибку.

Что необходимо поменять для `sum` ?

```
sum: function($el) {
        var re = /[0-9]/;
        return re.test($el.val());
    },
```

полный код:

```
 var validator = {
        required: function($el) {
            return $el.val() != '';
        },
        sum: function($el) {
            var re = /[0-9]/;
            return re.test($el.val());
        },
        markAsError: function($el) {
            $el.addClass('error');
        }
    };

    $('#validateForm').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            $inputs = $this.find('input[type!="submit"]'),
            is_valid = true;

        $inputs.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                rules = $this.data('validate').split(' ');

            for(var i = 0, ci = rules.length; i < ci; i++) {
                if(!validator[rules[i]]($this)) {
                    validator.markAsError($this);

                    $this.next().html(validator.messages(rules[i]));

                    is_valid &= false;
                    return;
                } else {
                    $this.removeClass('error');
                    $this.next().html('');
                }
            }
        });
        return is_valid;
    });
```

Comment: немного изменила, но пока не понимаю как вызвать валидатор

`var validator = {
        required: function($el) {
            return $el.val() != '';
        },
        sum: function($el) {
            var re = (function (m){
                if(m.value < 100){
                    return re.test($el.val());
                }
            });

        },
        markAsError: function($el) {
            $el.addClass('error');
        }
    };`

Comment: вызов валидатора уже реализован в коде. все они вызываются по порядку в цикле `for`

Comment: я убрала регулярные выражения, и сейчас не работает

Comment: тогда я, наверное, не понимаю вопроса.

Comment: Неужели так сложно привести в вопросе **минимальный** пример кода, воспроизводящий проблему?

Comment: совершенно не сложно, минимальный пример кода изначально приведен в вопросе. а вообще мне помогли реализовать проверку совсем по-другому. в проекте используется prototype.js который мне совершенно не знаком...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте регулярное выражение.

```
sum: function($el) {
    var re = /^[1-9][0-9][0-9]+/;
    return re.test($el.val());
}
```

В квадратных скобках перечисляются разрешённые символы, знак `+` означает, что выражение должно повториться 1 и более раз, `^` означает начало строки.
Таким образом, выражение `/^[1-9][0-9][0-9]+/` означает, что:

- строка должна состоять из 3 или более цифр подряд;
- начинаться не с нуля (`^[1-9]`);

Comment: регулярные выражения тут не подходят

Comment: почему? этого не сказано в вопросе.

Comment: регулярные выражения используются для проверки текста? я правильно понимаю? 

а мне нужно определить "минимальную сумму 100" т.е. число

Comment: @MarinaVoronova У вас что пользователем вводится? Число "100" или выражение типа "81 + 19"? (или ещё что-то?)

Comment: пользователь должен ввести число не менее 100

Comment: @MarinaVoronova тогда я вас правильно понял. попробуйте один из предложенных ответов и [отметьте его принятым](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), если считаете ответ хорошим.

Comment: "001000" будет давать положительный результат, "ывфв100" будет давать положительный результат

Answer (score 1):

Вместо регулярки можно сделать простую проверку

```
sum: function($el) {
    return +$el.val() >= 100;
}
```

ВНИМАНИЕ! в этом решении НЕ проверяется, что пользователь ввёл число.

Comment: `val()` возвращает строку

Comment: Это JavaScript, строка автоматически конвертнётся в число. Пример: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_comparison_21

Comment: в данном случае да - но не всегда, иногда число преобразуется в строку

Comment: @Grundy, сделал конвертацию явной.

Comment: "001000" будет давать положительный результат

Comment: этот ответ мне не пригодился, т.к. реализовали по-другому. но он наиболее мне понятен)

Comment: @korytoff в вопросе про ведущие нули ничего не сказано

Answer (score 0):

Если проверка по одному полю:

```
sum: function($el) {
    var re = /^[0-9]{3,}$/;
    return re.test($el.val()) && parseInt($el.val()) >= 100;
},
```

Comment: не сработает для чисел > 999

Comment: @naXa, да, опечатался, поправил